# Finding bounds of merged cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to determine the bounds of a merged cell (it's starting cell and its ending cell).

This is for a scheduling tool, where I'm using these two rows as a sort of calendar. I tried setting up a range for the starting cell and the ending cell using .Count, but wasn't having any luck as both were outputting the starting cell address.

```
Set rDate = Sheet1.Range("G2:" & sCol & "3")
Set rMonth = rDate.Find(sMonth)

    If rDate.MergeCells Then
        Set rStart = rDate.Cells(1, 1)
        Set rEnd = rDate.Cells(rDate.Rows.Count, rDate.Columns.Count)
    End If

MsgBox rStart.Address
MsgBox rEnd.Address
```

Both ranges are outputting G2 as the address. I've attached an image of the problem as well.

[image]

Comment: Use [`Range.MergeArea`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.mergearea) maybe.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what [`Range.MergeArea`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.mergearea) is:

> Returns a **Range** object that represents the merged range containing the specified cell. If the specified cell isn't in a merged range, this property returns the specified cell.

```
If rDate.MergeCells ' not really necessary, unless you only want to work with a merged cell
    MsgBox rDate.MergeArea.Address
End If
```

Also to note, you reference a merged cell by its topmost, leftmost cell:

```
Set rDate = Range("G2") 'this is still a merged cell.
```

If you want to reference the starting and ending cells, perhaps something like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rDate As Range
    Set rDate = Sheet1.Range("G2")

    If rDate.MergeCells Then
        Dim startAddress As String
        startAddress = Split(rDate.MergeArea.Address, ":")(0)

        Dim endAddress As String
        endAddress = Split(rDate.MergeArea.Address, ":")(1)
    End If

    MsgBox "The start address is " & startAddress & _
           " and the end address is " & endAddress & "."
End Sub
```

Comment: I want to be able to output both the starting cell of the merged cell, and the ending cell. I tried the above code, and it gave me a run time error 1004: "Application defined, or object defined error".

Comment: @JordanChancellor see my edit on how to reference the merged cell.

Comment: Maybe I'm confusing myself, my apologies. If a cell is merged from A3 to G3, is there a way to output G3 alone? I think I understand how to output the starting cell by referencing the top left corner of the range, but my issue really lies with outputting that ending boundary cell.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
MsgBox rStart.Address
MsgBox rStart.MergeArea(rStart.MergeArea.Count).Address
```